# Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' on Centos 7.6.1810 using remi-php72 repo

Tags: php, centos7, php-ziparchive

I am having problems getting October CMS to update:

Update failed
"Class 'ZipArchive' not found" on line 51 of /var/www/html/jdd/htdocs/vendor/october/rain/src/Filesystem/Zip.php

And if I do php -m, i get the following warning:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so: undefined symbol: zip_libzip_version), /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Strange thing is, in my /etc/php.d/ folder, the zip.ini file contains the line: extension=zip.so. whereas all other .ini files in /php.d do not include the ".so" extension (eg: for the json.ini file, the line reads: extension=json). I have tried removing the ".so" from the zip.ini extension= line, but it still won't work.

As far as I know, the system is only running x86_64 executables (how do I check this with absolute certainty - all binaries are showing as .x86_64 or .noarch?).

I have tried other versions of php:
-php 5.4 installs zip.so fine (it loads correctly), except October requires at least php 7.0.
-php 7.0 to 7.3 all install zip.so, but the extension still does not load.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Okay, I figured out that the file extension of the PHP shared object name is now left out with PHP 7.3, so no error in my php.d/ .ini files there.

Still stuck with the problem of an installed, but not recognised zip.so.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same problem and found following solution:

1. Search for installed php modules:

`yum list installed | grep php*`

2. Try to locate installed php-zip module:

`rpm -ql php72-php-pecl-zip`

3. You will see something like this:

```
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/40-zip.ini
/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so # <----
/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/zip
```

4. Then just create symlink to this file in directory where php searches modules by default:

`ln -s /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so`

After this steps I finally saw zip extension in `php -m` output and now can use class `ZipArchive`.

Also you should probably restart your httpd service.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the right solution. See https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl   (so php-pecl-zip vs php72-php-pecl-zip)

Answer (score 2):

1 - Download manually the last ZIP pecl lib at https://pecl.php.net/package/zip

2 - Install it with pecl in the downloaded file

```
sudo pecl install zip-1.19.1.tgz
```

3 Enable zip on php.ini

```
extension=zip
```

Comment: I think this should be marked as solution. I had similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and ondrej ppa php7.4. After I did apt-get dist-upgrade zlib became newer then one ondrej used. Uninstalling php7.4-zip from ppa and installing from pecl solved issue (you need to install php7.4-dev and libzip-dev to be able to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Please check you are using latest libzip5 version 1.5.1 from remi-safe repository (which is mandatory, and enabled by default)

Comment: Remi, I have tried another repository with success.

I must have somehow disabled the repo or missed enabling it. I am not sure if this was the problem, or not, -  Could this have created the problem?

Comment: I will check on the next PHP install whether this was the reason, but for now, I will continue with what I have managed to install. Thanks!